# How to use a global server side variable in Nuxtjs v2 without Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I need a global server side only variable without the Vuex store because it "polutes" the window._*NUXT*_ object hydration element. The data i want to use are approx. ~300kb and they are gettings used only for render components, after that they are obsolete. Also i dont need these elements to get hydrated.

The options i have researched are custom render template in Nuxt but it lacks documentation.

Thank you in advance!

I have already tried changing the scope of the data from store to each major component but the data still travel to the client via window._*NUXT*_.data instead of windows._*NUXT*_.state.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a store do this using a middleware or Pinia. Middleware allows you to define create custom functions and rendering on all pages

See this to use a middleware
https://debbie.codes/blog/nuxt-middleware/

Using Pinia
https://pinia.vuejs.org/getting-started.html

Comment: The isssue is that store state will get hydrated to client side and it means a huge load of uneccesary data.